# "food which riches of fats" or "food which riches with fats"?

Tags: idioms

What is correct from these two options (or maybe other option)?

> a) "It's not healthy to eat foods which rich of fats"
>
> b) "It's not healthy to eat foods which rich with fats"

Comment: Neither version is valid English. In principle, *It's not healthy to eat foods which **are** rich **in** fats*. But given ***rich*** normally has positive associations which don't sit well in this context, *It's not healthy to eat foods which are **high** in fat* is far more likely. The matter of whether to use the less common plural form ***fats*** in this context is a bit too complex to address in a comment, so I'd suggest you just stick with the singular form. Also note that usually, *It's not healthy = **It's unhealthy***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. Take your pick from:

> "It's not healthy to eat foods rich in fats."
>   "It's not healthy to eat foods which are rich in fats."

*Which* shouldn't be used on its own like that; it needs to go with a linking verb like *are/aren't*, *is/isn't*, etc.